# Tkinter .pack layout understanding

Tags: layout, tkinter, frame, pack

I have a problem with my layout : i would like the right button to be next to the blue button, but i don't know how.. and i would like to use pack and not grid.
I thought, that my 4 colour buttons were in one frame (named `frame`), and so that if I put another frame in `root`,which is placed right, it would be on "top right" as much as possible, and not at the lower right. 
Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

bottomframe = Frame(frame)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

rightframe = Frame(root)
rightframe.pack(side=RIGHT)

redbutton = Button(frame, text="Red", fg="red")
redbutton.pack( side = LEFT)

greenbutton = Button(frame, text="Brown", fg="brown")
greenbutton.pack( side = LEFT )

bluebutton = Button(frame, text="Blue", fg="blue")
bluebutton.pack( side = LEFT )

blackbutton = Button(bottomframe, text="Black", fg="black")
blackbutton.pack( side = BOTTOM)

rightbutton = Button(rightframe, text = "right", fg="black")
rightbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want the right button next to the blue button, why don't you put it in the same frame as the blue button?

Comment: My advice is to start by giving each frame a unique color so that it's easier to visualize what is happening. Next, be sure to use the `sticky` option to help widgets fill the area that they are placed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use an individual frame for the two buttons, then pack it where you want:

```
miniframe=Frame(Root)
bluebutton = Button(miniframe, text="Blue", fg="blue")
bluebutton.pack( side = LEFT )
Leftbutton = Button(miniframe, text="Left", fg="black")
bluebutton.pack( side = LEFT )
```

Comment: True that ! Thanks!